# Select a sequence of columns: `:` works but not `seq`

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to subset a dataset by selecting some columns from a data.table. However, my code does not work with some variations.

Here is a sample data.table

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table( ID = 1:50,
            Capacity = sample(100:1000, size = 50, replace = F),
            Code = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 50, replace = T),
            State = rep(c("Alabama","Indiana","Texas","Nevada"), 50))
```

Here is a working subset code, where a numeric sequence of columns is specified using `:`:

```
DT[ , 1:2]
```

However, specifying the *same* sequence of columns using `seq` does not work:

```
DT[ , seq(1:2)]
```

Note that this works with a dataframe but not with a data.table.

I need something along the lines of the second format because I'm subsetting based on the output of `grep()` and it gives the same output as the second format. What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Using `with=FALSE` makes the second one work, but I don't know why it doesn't work in the first place.

Comment: @RichScriven thanks for the pointer! Using that, I dug deeper with ?data.table. This line seems to indicate why. "When with=FALSE, j can only be a vector of column names or positions to select (as in data.frame).".

Comment: @RichScriven see [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41781264/2761575) why `:` works but `seq` does not

Comment: Please note that `data.table` version 1.9.8 had "POTENTIALLY BREAKING CHANGES". E.g. around defaults for unique and unquoted variable names in j now returning vectors. It scrambled my old clunky `data.table` code. When people look at old Stack Overflow solutions and find it is no longer working then its worth looking at the [1.9.8 release notes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/news.html) before insanity kicks in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On recent versions of data.table, numbers can be used in `j` to specify columns. This behaviour includes formats such as `DT[,1:2]` to specify a numeric range of columns. (Note that this syntax does not work on  older versions of data.table).

So why does `DT[ , 1:2]` work, but `DT[ , seq(1:2)]` does not?  The answer is buried in the code for `data.table:::[.data.table`, which includes the lines:

```
  if (!missing(j)) {
    jsub = replace_dot_alias(substitute(j))
    root = if (is.call(jsub)) 
      as.character(jsub[[1L]])[1L]
    else ""
    if (root == ":" || (root %chin% c("-", "!") && is.call(jsub[[2L]]) && 
        jsub[[2L]][[1L]] == "(" && is.call(jsub[[2L]][[2L]]) && 
        jsub[[2L]][[2L]][[1L]] == ":") || (!length(all.vars(jsub)) && 
            root %chin% c("", "c", "paste", "paste0", "-", "!") && 
            missing(by))) {
      with = FALSE
    }
```

We can see here that `data.table` is automatically setting the `with = FALSE` parameter for you when it detects the use of function `:` in `j`.  It doesn't have the same functionality built in for `seq`, so we have to specify `with = FALSE` ourselves if we want to use the `seq` syntax.

```
DT[ , seq(1:2), with = FALSE]
```

Comment: I think it'd be more helpful to direct the OP and other readers (like me) to some relevant place in the docs and/or NEWS.

Comment: @Frank I'm not sure that this is actually documented anywhere.  I had to look in the source code to find the reason....

Comment: Item #3 in the 1.9.8 release notes covers it. I just assumed they updated the docs to reflect the change: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-v198--on-cran-25-nov-2016

Comment: @dww that explains the issue I was having, thank you!

Comment: @Frank, yes - the use of `:` in j, since ver 1.9.8, is documented (e.g. in the link you provided) and is increasingly common knowledge amongst data.table users. But the point of OP's question is why `seq` does not work in the same way as `:`. The answer to that isn't in the documentation anywhere i can see (although one could argue that it should be), its buried in the source code.

Answer (score 6):

The lesson I learned is to use `list` instead of `c`:

```
 DT[ ,list(ID,Capacity)]
 #---------------------------
     ID Capacity
  1:  1      483
  2:  2      703
  3:  3      924
  4:  4      267
  5:  5      588
 ---            
196: 46      761
197: 47      584
198: 48      402
199: 49      416
200: 50      130
```

It lets you ignore those pesky quotations, and it also moves you in the direction of seeing the `j` argument as an evaluated expression with an environment of the datatable itself.

To 'get' the named columns by number use the `mget` function and the `names` function. R 'names' are language elements, i.e., data objects in the search path from the current environment. Column names of dataframes are not actually R `names`. So you need a function that will take a character value and cause the interpreter to consider it a fully qualified `name`. Datatable-[-function syntax for the j item does handle column names as language objects rather than character values as would the `[.data.frame`-function:

```
DT[ ,mget(names(DT)[c(1,2)])]
     ID Capacity
  1:  1      483
  2:  2      703
  3:  3      924
  4:  4      267
  5:  5      588
 ---            
196: 46      761
197: 47      584
198: 48      402
199: 49      416
200: 50      130
```

Comment: i like 'list' too, its just if the OP plans on selecting columns with grep, i suggested with=FALSE might be more compatible with that. But list for sure captures the meaning of data.table better

Comment: @42-, thanks for your answer! Using the list approach, how would I access the columns by their indices, as opposed to names? DT[,list(c(1,2))] does not appear to work, either.

Comment: c(1,2) doesn't evaluate to anything useful. Can also "map" back to "language" value(s) with `get` or `mget`. See above.

Comment: @42-, thank you! Using `mget` seems like a convoluted way to do it, though, when DT[,c(1,2)] just works as well...

Comment: It works on in the very latest version of data.table. It was what you would have needed to do if that were you goal at any time in the past.

Answer (score 4):

The main issue here is that columns in data.table are referenced objects so you cannot use the same syntax as data.frame. ie no quoted names or numbers

so `DT[,c("ID", "Capacity")]` won't work for the same reason that `DT[,seq(1:2)]` won't work.

However, adding `,with=FALSE` causes the data.table to work be referenced as a data.frame would be

so `DT[,c("ID", "Capacity"), with=FALSE]` AND `DT[,seq(1:2), with=FALSE]` now give you what you want.

```
     ID Capacity
  1:  1      913
  2:  2      602
  3:  3      861
  4:  4      967
  5:  5      374
 ---            
196: 46      163
197: 47      254
198: 48      390
199: 49      853
200: 50      486
```

EDIT: as pointed out by @Rich Scriven

Comment: Thank you! A question though. Isn't seq(1:2) the same as 1:2 for subsetting? I'm curious because one works, and the other doesn't.

Comment: honestly not entirely sure what the difference is. Also not sure why 1:2 worked for you because it doesn't work for me. Either way using with=FALSE together with grep as you intended works fine.

Comment: `DT[,c("ID", "Capacity")]` works with the newest version of data.table.  So does `DT[, 1:2]`, which is why I was stumped that `DT[, seq(1, 2)]` doesn't work.

Comment: Exactly. I guess I'm using the newest version, and I saw the same behavior as @RichScriven and, hence, my confusion.

Comment: Hmm, must be time for me to update. data.table is maintained by a small but very dedicated core of people. They are constantly integrating suggestions from the community and it might be worthwhile for you to report this issue to them directly